# Gradient tool on smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, gradient, smartobject

I am trying to create a star, with a gradient color effect. When I try to use the gradient color tool I get the message

> Could not use the gradient tool because the
>   content of the layer is not directly editable

[image]

There is one "solution" but I don't think is too direct. I can rasterize the layer and using the `laso` tool to select the region I would like to color, use the `gradient` tool to make the color effect.

Is there any other way around it?

Comment: You need to double click the smart object to edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can´t use gradient tool on shape or smart object in PS, when you want to add gradient to your star just open blending options ( right click on that layer > blending options ), and check and set gradient overlay